# Why isn't my F Stop changing on my Nikon D7200?

Tags: aperture, f-stop, nikon-d7200

I can use the dial but the number never goes up or down. It stays at 0. I tried holding down the +/- while turning the front dial and it just adjusts the amount of light coming into the view finder. And some days it's not a 0, but I still can't manually adjust. Not sure if its my lens that's making it no budge or my camera body? The lens that I use for reference is a Nikon AF Nikon 28-105 mm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - could you provide a picture or something of the bits of the display you're referring to? Technically, an f-stop will _never_ be zero, so I suspect you're looking at something else, possibly exposure correction. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

F0 with a triangle next to it is a Nikon error code for no lens communication.

Try cleaning the contacts and remounting the lens. If neither works, try another lens. If that doesn't work the camera probably needs repair. If a different lens does work, then the 28-105 needs repair.

Answer (score 0):

If the Nikon lens is an older version (with an aperture ring), you need to have the aperture on the highest setting (e.g. 22), for the camera to engage the AF computer within the camera. I made this mistake when I purchased some older AF-D style primes.